# How can I get the checkbox' value in the header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I am using the jQuery plugin [Flexigrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241752%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) which has the checkbox attached with every row, and the checkbox in the header can make the rows all checked.

Now I am making a dialog which has a Flexigrid in it, when I press a button. I want the dialog popup and make the checkbox in the header to be "checked" and when I leave the dialog, make it unchecked. But how can I do it?

Comment: Please post up the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: allright  I've got it. just use                                   $('th input[type="checkbox"]',$( the dialog)).attr("checked",false);

Answer (score 0):

All right, I've got it. Just use:

```
$('th input[type="checkbox"]',$( the dialog)).attr("checked",false);
```